# SUBQuery NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

I have a an Array of Dictionaries, in which phone numbers is one key,

```
{
        Email = "ryuiioo@uioo.njk";
        Firstname = Sourish;
        Lastname = Sam;
        Middlename = S;
        phonenumbers =         (
                        {
                Home = 3452345345;
                Main = 4985739804;
                Mobile = 3567567741;
                Other = 5769875698;
                Test = 2290834709;
                Testing = 9336664648;
                Work = 4523523453;
                iPhone = 3453245234;
            }
        );
        recordID = 66;
    }
```

I am searching the array with this string "**stringToSearch**".
This is the way I am trying to get the first name while searching

```
NSMutableArray *allPredicatesArray = [NSMutableArray new];
NSPredicate *firstNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.Firstname beginswith[c] %@",stringToSearch];
NSArray *firstNameFilteredArray = [self.recordsMutableArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:firstNamePredicate];
[allPredicatesArray addObjectsFromArray:firstNameFilteredArray];
```

Now, can i get using predicates the "Mobile" number search using NSpredicates

Answer (score 1):

"phonenumbers" is an *array*, therefore you have to use "ANY" in the predicate:

```
NSString *numberToSearch = @"3567567741";
NSPredicate *mobileNumberPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY phonenumbers.Mobile BEGINSWITH %@", numberToSearch];
```

assuming that the number is stored as a string.

Answer (score 1):

If phone numbers is not actually an array of dictionaries, I think what you're wanting is the predicate string `SELF.phonenumbers.Mobile beginswith[c] %@"`

If it actually is an array of dictionaries, then the following will work:

```
@"SUBQUERY(phonenumbers, $x, $x.Mobile BEGINSWITH %@).@count > 0"
```

Comment: May i know what is "$x" here ??

Comment: The short answer is it's appearance in the second argument defines a placeholder that will be expanded in the third argument.  Look around SO and google and you should find quite a few long explanations of SUBQUERY in NSPredicate.

Comment: In this particular case it's probably overkill as Martin R's answer will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with following code:

```
NSPredicate *predicateProduct = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Mobile BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", stringToSearch];
NSArray *filteredArray = [self.listOfProducts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateProduct];
NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);
```

Comment: This won't work as we have phone numbers as  key and to that we have NSarray linked to it.